# Passing service account(json file) location to application.properties

Tags: java, maven, google-app-engine

I have one maven project which wanted to have service account(json file) for authentication and maven should product the .war not .jar.

Considering that, I wanted to specify the json file location into project application.properties, like this:

> spring.cloud.gcp.credentials.location=file:src/main/resources/service-account/service-account-key.json

I am new to the .war world, now the problem is when i build the project locally I am able to get the json file as it is in my resource folder and I am using tomcat locally which is working fine.

But in case of when i deploy into google app engine and its war nature service-account-key.json file is not found on the mentioned location.

Can anyone help on the same, where i need to put in for that as a part of build only i can refer and use the service account json file at both the time locally and after deploy as well.

thanks for you help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

According to Google Cloud documentation you have two choices for providing the credentials to your application:
1. Set the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable explicitly.
2. Pass the path to the service account in code.
You can check this link for more information: https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#auth-cloud-implicit-java

Answer (score 0):

You can reference the file in resources by prepending *classpath:* instead of *file:*

See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62085016/1525529).